# How to check for one value in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Whats the best way to check if different groups of rows in a table with the same GroupID such as different teams have a SINGLE captain? Captain Identifier for example could be '10', so its crucial that it goes through multiple records with the same groupID and checks to see if theres ONLY ONE record with the positionID as '10'. I need it to do it for all teams, i.e all groupID's

```
-------------------------------------------------
ID | Group ID | Name | Position|
-------------------------------------------------
1       1       John     3
2       1       jim      3
3       1       Hahn     4
4       1       Mary     4
5       1       Moe      4
6       1       Charlie  10
7       2       taylor   4
8       2       Geoff    4
9       2       adam     4
10      2       cam      10
11      3       sharon   2
12      3       tony     4
13      3       steve    3
14      3       eve      4
15      3       gwen     10
--------------------------------
```

So what I need it to do is check that every groupID only had ONE 10 as the position.

Thanks in advance guys. Check out the image link at the bottom.

im using mysql btw

Sorry if this is badly described

Comment: Can you add table definition, some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I think I understand that you are confused.  I have not idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ideally what SQL you have right now that's not working as well.  There's probably a few ways to tackle it, and unless you're sifting through tens of millions of records, the "best" way is simply whatever works usually.  This will at least give us an idea of how you're currently trying to work with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want an indication that will tell you whether the groupID had more then one captain.

So what you need is this:

```
select groupID,case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 0 end as IND_ONE_CAPTAIN from (
select groupID, sum(case when positionid = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from players
group by groupID)
```

Now IND_ONE_CAPTAIN columns consist 1 or 0, 1 is for the group id only had 1 captain, and 0 is when they had more.

Comment: Very humbly I'll say that my answer is more compact having a single query

Comment: He wanted to check for each team if they have more then 1 captain or not, not select only them. So, my answer is more correct(btw my inner query does exactly the same as yours) @zahiromor

Comment: It is ironic that the OP accepted a query that would generate an error if run in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you - I think you need something like :

```
select groupId, sum(case when positionID='10' then 1 else 0 end) as captains   
from tbl_name
group by groupID
having captains = 1
```

am I close???

Comment: Changing the `count()` to `sum()` makes the query correct.

Comment: tnx @GordonLinoff  my pleasure and privilege to be edited by you :)